# how to use act as taggable on first time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

please somebody help me how can i use acts-as-taggable-on first time.i want to tag my messages  in messages controller .i installed it properly through command gem install acts-as-taggable-on and successfully run the migration .But now what to do further please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ravindra, please read the instructions here: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/